# Выборка с вложенными запросами в MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, база-данных, запрос-в-запросе

Есть четыре таблицы, основной запрос я делаю к таблице `users`, из которой будет извлечена одно строка, из других я хочу извлечь все данные. Так я это делаю:

```
SELECT  `u`.`id`, `u`.`login`, 
`resource`.`tid` AS `typeID`, `resource`.`files` AS `icon`, 
`type`.`params` AS `resourceData`, 
`cats`.`id` AS `cid`, `cats`.`name` AS `cname`,
 `types`.`id` AS `tid`, `types`.`name` AS `tname`  

 FROM `users` `u`  
 LEFT JOIN `resources` `resource` ON `resource`.`id`=`u`.`imgID`   
 LEFT JOIN `cats` `cats` ON `cats`.`id`>1  
 LEFT JOIN `types` `types` ON `types`.`id`>1   
 WHERE `u`.`id` = 8189
```

В результате, я получаю множество строк, с дублирующими данными из таблицы `users`. Но такой способ мне не подходит, т.к. по мере добавления join'ов это кол-во дублирующих строк увеличивается, и получается не то что хочется. А хочется, на выходе получить результат с массивом вида:

```
{
    "id": "8189",
    "login": "userName",
    "typeID": "226",
    "icon": "filename.jpg",
    "cats": ["большой массив с полями cname и cid"],
    "types": ["большой массив с полями tname и tid"]
        //и так далее
}
```

Вместо join нужно использовать что-то другое, подскажите, как добиться желаемого результата?

Comment: вообще mysql слабо для этого подходит, но можно попробовать `group_concat()`, только у него ограничения на длину. Возможно, в вашем случае будет лучше делать отдельными запросами и собирать все это на клиенте

Comment: Есть вложенные запросы, что-то типа как с помощью `IN`, но немного другое, вот сейчас не могу сообразить

Comment: @Mike, ну допустим я использую `join`, можно ли как-то отфильтровать то большое кол-во строк, чтобы они не дублирующие хотя бы были? Чтобы в результате пройтись в массиве только по одному полю. Не очень удобно в моем случае делать несколько отдельных запросов

Comment: @Mike, ок, распишите)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Реляционные БД в принципе возвращают результат исключительно в виде плоской таблицы. в которой есть колонки и строки. SQL не предназначен для работы с многомерными данными. (В некоторых СУБД есть массивы, но это другая история). Так что построить такой массив вы можете только на клиенте. Что бы обойтись одним запросом и при этом не было дублирования записей из подчиненных таблиц в голову приходит пока только выводить их лесенкой, примерно так:

```
select * from main m
  join (select 1 X union select 2 union select 3) N
  left join slave1 s1 on s1.m_id=m.id and N.X=1
  left join slave2 s2 on s2.m_id=m.id and N.X=2
  left join slave3 s3 on s3.m_id=m.id and N.X=3
```

Данные на выходе будут выглядеть примерно так:

```
main.id  slave1.val  slave2.val  slave3.val
1            A         NULL        NULL
1            B         NULL        NULL
1          NULL         X          NULL
1          NULL         Y          NULL
1          NULL        NULL          Z
```

Код, использующий данный запрос должен добавлять значения в соответствующий подмассив только в случае если в обрабатывамой строке значения колонок соответствующей подмассиву таблицы не NULL.

[SQLFIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a07339/2)

Comment: @sanu0074 это решение не реализует того что пожелал автор вопроса, Вопрос то был по поводу - как вывести одним запросом несвязанные данные без перемножения строк в результате. А предложенное тут решение как раз работает со связанными данными (в инструкциях 'on' указана связь по ключевым полям,что нормально)
Автор, определись

Answer (score 0):

Join в запросах предназначен для выборки связанных данных (условие связи в разделе 'on' должно явно задавать соответствие полей-ссылок включаемой в join таблицы к ключевым полям какой-то уже указанной ранее). Например получаем продавцов (одна таблица) и связанные с нимм продажи (другая). в этом случае мы получим для каждого найденного продавца набор нескольких строк соответствующих им продаж. Общее число строк будет равно общему количеству найденных продаж.
    Если же join применить к несвязанным данным (как в показанном в топике примере) - то при выполнении join'-а каждая из существующих строк будет размножена на количество строк выбираемых из присоединяемой таблицы (формально каждая из строк присоединяемой таблицы будет соответствовать каждой уже отобранной строке уже обработанных таблиц - что и будет реализовано).

Например в данном случае не указано условия соответствия cats и users, т.е. каждому из users будет соответствовать каждая из cats, получим набор строк со всеми возможными комбинациями. Также и при присоединении types - еще раз помножим количество комбинаций.
    Если сущности (users + resoures), types и cats как-то связаны в жизни, то необходимо это указывать в join'-е, если нет, то выбирать их отдельными несвязанными запросами: (users + resoures), types, cats

Comment: В данном примере мы хотим извлечь все cats и types, они не обязательно должны соответствовать конкретной записи из users. Суть задачи в том чтобы извлечь все записи из cats и types в одном сложном запросе

Comment: @sanu0074 , если никак не ограничивать условие выборки второго (и последующих) множества строк, то получаем правило - каждая строка из первого множества соответствует каждой из второго, такой результат и получаем. Это не 'join' неправильный, это не продумана логика. Если множества в принципе не связаны, то не надо их увязывать друг с другом, а загружать раздельно